# Dotnet 3.1 background service running from singleton

Tags: .net, .net-core, background-service

I have a background service intialized on my StartUp, i use this service only for queue consumer. It's uses a singleton service that have a subscriber method to handle queue consumes.
As a singleton intialiazed on StartUp i expected that it will make only one connection, but after every queue message that i reveive it's creating a new connection. I want to know how to make only one connection for the consumer.
I'm using dotnet 3.1 and rabbitMQClient lib

My code looks like this:

I inject my singleton in my StartUp like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
           
    services.AddSingleton<EasyNetQMessageQueuer<RegisterUserResponseEvent>>();
    services.AddControllers();
}
```

And i add a back service on the Configure method like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
     }

     app.UseRouting();

     app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
     {
         endpoints.MapControllers();
     });

     app.UseQueueConsumer();
}
```

This back service come from this class below:

```
private static EasyNetQMessageQueuer<RegisterUserResponseEvent> _queuer;

public static IApplicationBuilder UseQueueConsumer(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    _queuer = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<EasyNetQMessageQueuer<RegisterUserResponseEvent>>();
    var lifetime = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IHostApplicationLifetime>();

    lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnStarted);
    lifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(OnStopping);

    return app;
}
        
private static void OnStarted()
{
    _queuer.Subscribe();
}
private static void OnStopping()
{
    _queuer.DisposeConnection();
}
```

Comment: Can you show more of your code that you have?  It's hard to tell what code comes from where.  Since you're registering `EasyNetQMessageQueuer<RegisterUserResponseEvent>` as a singleton, you should be able to accept that in one of your dependencies without creating a `static` variable anywhere.

Comment: @Matthew this one is static becouse i am not injection it with constructor. I edited the question to provide more code :)